# Reversing a(n) (Underscore-)sorted array removes properties from objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, meteor, underscore.js

**EDIT:**

I've recorded the bug with quicktime, for your viewing pleasure. Hope this helps a bit more with solving this weird issue.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/o72o1v1eqvrarb7/Weird%20Sorting%20Bug.mov?dl=0

for more code details, see:

https://www.pastebin.com/zUts9qmg

---

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

I have a weird issue. I'm using Meteor for developing an application, and one of its dependancies is Underscore.js. Handy little tool, but I ran across a weird issue (bug, maybe?).

Sorting an array of objects works fine, but reversing it doesn't. When reversing the array, data from the objects inside the array gets deleted...

I create a table, with a sticky header and dynamically add the table body.

[image: Example of table used]

Clicking on one of the columns in the header of the table fires up some code:

```
if (sortId != event.target.id) {
    sortAsc = true;
    sortId = event.target.id;
}

if (!sortAsc) {
    requirements = _.sortBy(requirements, event.target.id).reverse();
} else {
    requirements = _.sortBy(requirements, event.target.id);
}

sortAsc = !sortAsc;

CreateTable();
```

The `sortId` is a string that represents which key we want to sort on. To get this `sortId`, we look at the `event.target.id`, which is the ID of the item we clicked on in the header of the table.
The `sortAsc` is a boolean that will determine wether we want to sort ascending or descending.
The `requirements` is the array with the data in a format like:

```
[
    {
        Status: "Something",
        ID: 1,
        Description: "Hahaha, yes!",
        Category: "Category: Dairy",
        segment: 1
    },
    {
        //etc...
    }
]
```

Using `Underscore.js`, I sort the array with the `_.sortBy([collection], [property to sort by]);`. This works as expected. It sorts all objects in the array by the supplied `sortId`. But, when reversing it, it deletes a property in all objects in the array, resulting in the table missing a column, and the styling going haywire:

[image: Logging before and after the reversing of the array]

[image: Here are the logs in the browser]

As you can see, after the reversing of the array, the `status` property of the object is gone. This goes for all 10 of the objects in the array.

I've tried sorting based on a hardcoded property, using a "custom" sorting function in the `_.sortBy` function, but they all have the same result. Even reversing the standard JavaScript sorting `.sort()` results in loss of data.

Does anyone know what's going on? Am I doing something wrong?

All help is much appreciated!

Comment: I don't think the problem is caused by `reverse`. Try putting `console.log(JSON.stringify(requirements[0]));` right before and after `requirements = _.sortBy(requirements, event.target.id).reverse();` to verify that `reverse` is really the cause.

Comment: The result: Before: `{"Status":"Delayed","ID":107,"Description":"Ability to validate the customer data against Unify (to check if customer details are allowed like foreign address or foreign back-account of foreign delivery address).","Category":"C1-SELL","segment":1}` and after: `{"ID":346,"Description":"The ability to support customer accounts including but not limited to : Receive customer payments at POS","Category":"C12-PAY","segment":1}`. http://imgur.com/a/xgwKO

Comment: @Magicbjørn That clearly is a different object, from a different position. Quite surely it didn't have a `.Status` before sorting/reversing either.

Answer (score 0):

`_.sortBy` returns `Array` and `reverse()` is called on this array, so it's not `underscore`'s issue.

Try to do this: `console.log(Array.prototype.reverse);`

The output should be `ƒ reverse() { [native code] }` or similar to it, depending on browser you're using. If you see anything other than `[native code]` — that means that you have another implementation of `reverse()` function that works incorrectly.

**Added:**

I suggest you to not use `reverse()` at all, and do all work just by sorting.

```
requirements.sort((a, b) => {
  const v1 = (sortAsc ? a : b)[sortId];
  const v2 = (sortAsc ? b : a)[sortId];
  return v1 < v2 ? -1 : ( v1 > v2 ? 1 : 0 );
});
```

Comment: It returns `function reverse() { [native code] }`, indeed. And yes, it's not Underscore's function, but Underscore does not have a function to inverse an array, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: That's really interesting issue. I've tried to reproduce it in Chrome, but I couldn't. Both `Status` and `status` fields were intact after reverse. Could you share more information/code, perhaps?

Comment: It is still deleting the "Status" property. I've tried some stuff myself, not with the reversing, but with the creation of the table and the creation of the array. I find now that reversing works every other time. So, the first reverse works, but when it's called a second time, the property gets deleted. The third reversing works as intended again... This is getting more weird by the minute...

Comment: Try to rename this `Status` property to something other.

Comment: Nope, still there. I added a link to a videofile of the bug in the original question.

Comment: That's really weird issue. Moreover, I've tried hard to reproduce it but had no such luck. Could you share the rest of your code? How do you obtain this array, what other actions are done on it etc.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/zUts9qmg This contains all relevant code. From clicking on a project (thus selecting it, and retrieving the requirements), to the creation of the table. Also included the sorting code as well.